# how i can compare changing API response body with expected API using restAssured

Tags: automated-tests, rest-assured

Hi, I am trying to create a API Automation Framework using Rest assured library what issue i am facing is the API response body is changing very frequently. Plz Help how i can compare changing API response body with expected API

Answer (score 0):

Use Response Specification or Object Mapping options. In the first you may create bunch of expectations in the second compare actual object with expected in the way you like. I prefer first option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to evaluating other tools take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) because one of the key features is being able to handle variable parts of the response.

For example, look at [fuzzy matching](https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching) and the [`contains`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains) keyword.